# Doubts on calculating path integrals using the Cauchy formula

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, solution-verification, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I have some questions on the following exercises

Calculate the following path integrals using the Cauchy formula:

a) $\oint_{|z|=1}(\frac{\exp(z)}{z}+1)dz=2\pi i\dot 2 =4\pi i$

Here I just take as $f(z)=e^z+1$ and as $\xi=0$ and I use the cauchy formula $f(\xi)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{∂B}\frac{f(z)}{z-\xi}dz$, right?

I know that there exists another part of the Cauchy's theorem that says:

*:$U \subset \mathbb{C}$ open, $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ holomorphic. Then the following applies:
$\oint_{\gamma}f(z)dz=0$ for all $\gamma$ closed integration path with $|\gamma| \subset U$ and $int(\gamma) \subset U$

I still haven't fully understood this part of the theorem and when to apply it and when not.
Because for me if I try to use (*) for a) I have:
$\oint_{|z|=1}(\frac{\exp(z)}{z}+1)dz=\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{\exp(z)}{z}dz+\oint_{|z|=1}1dz$

Now we know that

$f(z):\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, $f(z)=1$ is holomorph and $|\gamma| \subset \mathbb{C}$ and $int(\gamma) \subset \mathbb{C}$ with $\gamma(t)=e^{it}$

Therefore $\oint_{|z|=1}1dz=0 \Rightarrow \oint_{|z|=1}\frac{\exp(z)}{z}dz+\oint_{|z|=1}1dz=2\pi i$

Now I can't understand which of the two results is correct because both make sense to me.

b) $\oint_{|z|=3}\frac{\cos(\pi z)}{z^2+1}dz=\oint_{|z|=3}=\oint_{|z|=3}\frac{}{z+i}+\frac{}{z-i}dz$, but from here I dont know how to proceed. Can someone help me?

c) $\oint_{|z-i|=1}\frac{\exp(\exp(z))}{(z-i)^3}dz=\frac{2 \pi i}{2} f^{(2)}(i)=\pi if^{(2)}(i)$.

Comment: $2\pi i$ is the correct answer for a). You can also use Cauchy's Integral Formula with $f(z)=e^{z}+z$.

Comment: okay but why? Because if I use this theorem: Let $U$ be an open subset of the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$, and suppose the closed disk $D$ defined $D=\{z:|z-z_{0}|\leq r\}$ is completely contained in $U$. Let $f : U → \mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function, and let $γ$ be the circle, oriented counterclockwise, forming the boundary of $D$. Then for every a in the interior of $D$:

${\displaystyle f(a)={\frac {1}{2\pi i}}\oint _{\gamma }{\frac {f(z)}{z-a}}\,dz.\,}$ 

The first result makes sense too. @geetha290krm

Comment: To use this theorem you have to take $f(z)=e^{z}+z$, not  $f(z)=e^{z}+1$.

Comment: you are right,... Thanks @geetha290krm 

For b) Can you help me too? Is with c) everything right?

Comment: c) is  wrong.  Do you know the Residue Theorem and the formula for $f^{n} (a)$ in terms of $\int \frac {f(z)} {(z-a)^{n}}$?

Comment: Do you mean this formula? ${\displaystyle f^{(n)}(a)={\frac {n!}{2\pi i}}\oint _{\gamma }{\frac {f(z)}{\left(z-a\right)^{n+1}}}\,dz.}$

I understand where my error is, in fact it should be $...=\pi i f^{(2)}(i)$ , right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (b) with Cauchy's Integral Formula:

$$\oint_{|z|=3}\frac{\cos\pi z}{z^2+1}dz=\frac1{2i}\oint_{|z|=3}\left[\frac{\cos\pi z}{z-i}-\frac{\cos\pi z}{z+i}\right]dz=$$

$$=\frac1{2i}2\pi i\left[\cos\pi i-\cos(-\pi i)\right]=\ldots$$

and now complete the easy end.

As for (c) and with the same formula as above (for derivatives, of course):

$$\oint_{|z-i|=1}\frac{e^{e^z}}{(z-i)^3}=\frac{2\pi i}{2!}\left(e^{e^z}\right)_{z=i}''=\ldots$$

and thus you are right in your comment.